# Exclude directory from loading

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

As I know, non-Python files (i.e. `file.sublime-menu`, `file.sublime-keymap`, etc.) can be located at ANY level inside package directory:

```
                                   Will be loaded? (Yes/No)

Packages
|-- Foo Package
|   |-- Old version
|   |   |-- foo.sublime-menu       Y - it is the problem
|   |   |-- foo.sublime-keymap     Y - it is the problem
|   |   |-- foo.py                 N
|   |
|   |-- foo.sublime-menu           Y
|   |-- foo.sublime-keymap         Y
|   |-- foo.py                     Y
```

I want to have `Old version` directory inside `Foo Package`, but the problem is that old menu and keymap files will be loaded. Is there a way to have some special file (call it `package.exclude` for example) with exclusion rules? Something like

```
exclude:
./Old version
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than changing the extension of the file to not be one that Sublime recognizes and loads, there is no way to stop it from finding and loading resources short of removing the file entirely or adding the package that they're stored in into the `ignored_packages` setting.